# Why is my Next13 Link refreshing the whole page?

Tags: next.js

I have a Next 13 app in which I am using the `/pages` directory. I have a `/projects` folder with a typical `Page` in it.

I am using a `Link` from `next/link` where I am routing to the `/projects` page. Here is an example of the link.

```
<Link href='/projects'>Projects</Link>
```

When I link to that page, I get a full page refresh.

BUT if I change the folder to `/projectz` and update the `Link` hrefs it routes to the page without refreshing the app.

I have validated in the middleware that there are no redirects happening. This is happening in some other manner.

Also, I am testing this with a Prod build. Does anyone have any idea where else this refresh could be happening at?

Comment: That's strange. Can you add your folder structure in the question? so we can see what file is there